# I want to retrive second record from a table in db2

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table workorder and attributes are wonum, pmnum, reportdate etc. I want a sql query which can retrive second record of the workorder having multiple pmnums. There are multiple workorders with each pm. i want the second last workorder (repordate desc) for each PM. Can someone help with this.

Comment: Show us some sample data and the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.) Also take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select wo.*
from (select wo.*,
             row_number() over (partition by wonum order by reportdate desc) as seqnum
      from workorder wo
     ) wo
where seqnum = 2;
```